# ReSharper custom pattern, extract text from string

Tags: c#, resharper

I have lots of code such as:

```
Resources.SettingName.ResourceManager.GetString("Setting")
```

which can be easily written as:

```
SettingName.Setting
```

I've been trying to write a custom pattern in Resharper to achieve this, but haven't succeeded yet.
Could somebody tell me what would be the right pattern?

ps: i use resharper 6.

Comment: I've tried different placeholders (argument, type, expression etc) but none of them worked.

Comment: I guess you can build a **Search** pattern but not a **Replace** pattern, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Visual Studio's Quick Find and Replace using Regular expressions:

Find What:

`Resources\.{.+}\.ResourceManager\.GetString\("{.+}"\)`

Replace with:

`\1.\2`

This assumes that your pattern conforms to: `Resources.`{some setting name}`.ResourceManager.SetString("`{some setting}`")`

Comment: I finally went with this solution. Also recorded it as a macro and bound it to a keyboard shortcut. The replace bit actually had to be `\1.\2`. Thanks.

Comment: @VishalShah - I have corrected this, not sure why I thought they were the other way around, anyway, it's good that it helped you achieve your results.